# processing last 10 working(business) days java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I tried to write a code which displays the days of the week for the last 10 dates.

Here's a part of the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
for(int i=0; i<=9;i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
    Date tday=cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dy = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
    String d9 = dy.format(tday);
    System.out.println(d9);
 }
```

Instead of showing all the last 10 days in an order it is displaying like this:

Thu
Wed
Mon
Fri
Mon
Wed
Thu
Thu
Wed
Mon
Fri

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: you want to write the code? what is stopping you from trying? my advice: first learn Java, at least well enough to be able to write it

Comment: Ok. All the best. Please go ahead. Let us know if you stuck in middle.

Comment: What about public Holidays???

Comment: You can get all the help you need from SO, but you need to show a little effort yourself first. What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: Sorry I didn't elaborate. I will try and post again for help. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
        boolean work = true;
        int day = 0; // 0 = today, 1 = yesterday etc...
        int subDay = 0; // subtract day 


        while (work){   
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get current time
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, subDay); // subtract day

        // working days are Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri. If we get saturdays or sundays, we want to skip that days,
        // so we use if declaration


        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            subDay--;
            continue;
        }



           Date tday=cal.getTime(); 
           SimpleDateFormat dy = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
           String d9 = dy.format(tday);
           System.out.println("Day: " + day + " - " + d9);  

           day ++; 
           subDay--;

           if (day >= 10){work=false;} // here we declara how much day we want to go back, and we break loop.

        }
```

Comment: I added some comments, hope it is everything clear now.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid j.u.Date

The first mistake was using the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Use a decent date-time library. In Java that means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time)

Both have their pros and cons.

Both offer a `LocalDate` class, which you need to represent a date-only without any time-of-day portion.

## Date-Time Versus Text

The Question’s code mixes date-time values with their String representations. Better to get your work done using date-time values. Afterwards, separately, create String representations for presentation to the user. The idea is a [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), to make your code more clear and easier to test/debug.

## Joda-Time

Example code in Java-Time.

You will have to specify which days of the week are business days.

Note the use of a time zone. The current date depends on your position on the globe (the time zone). A new day dawns in Paris earlier than in Montréal. If you omit the time zone, the JVM’s default is applied. Better to specify, even by calling `getDefault()`, than to rely on an implicit default.

First we gather a collection of desired date-time values.

```
int requiredCountOfDays = 10; // The Question demands 10 previous working days.
List<LocalDate> days = new ArrayList<LocalDate>( requiredCountOfDays );  // Collect desired LocalDate objects.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Specify time zone by which to get current date.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( timeZone ); // Get the current date at this moment in specified time zone.
LocalDate localDate = today; // Define var to decrement for previous days.
while ( days.size() < requiredCountOfDays ) { // Loop until we fill the list (10 elements).
    localDate = localDate.minusDays( 1 ); // Decrement to get previous day.
    // Hard-code what days are business days vs weekend days.
    boolean isWeekend = ( ( localDate.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY ) || ( localDate.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ) ); // Hard-coding for weekend because it is easier to type than coding for the more numerous week days.
    if ( !isWeekend ) { // If business day…
        days.add( localDate ); // …collect this day.
    }
}
```

Afterwards, we present those values in a localized String format.

```
List<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<String>( days.size() ); // Collect the same number of LocalDate objects, rendered as Strings.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE" ); // Generate name of day-of-week, abbreviated.
for ( LocalDate day : days ) {
   String dayOfWeek = formatter.print( day ); // Generate String representation.
   daysOfWeek.add( dayOfWeek ); // Collect the string.
}
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "days: " + days );
System.out.println( "daysOfWeek: " + daysOfWeek );
```

When run…

```
days: [2014-06-18, 2014-06-17, 2014-06-16, 2014-06-13, 2014-06-12, 2014-06-11, 2014-06-10, 2014-06-09, 2014-06-06, 2014-06-05]
daysOfWeek: [Wed, Tue, Mon, Fri, Thu, Wed, Tue, Mon, Fri, Thu]
```